# Drupal Theme Management

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-themes

i was using drupal6 for my project. i am using two different themes for front end and backend. i managed my frontend page.tpl.php as per my requirements. But if i logged in with admin username & password, i am landing on http://mywebsite/user/1 ( my account page ) . Problem is My account page in Administrator part was taking FRONT END THEME. It has to take backend theme. Apart from My account link, remaining links are taking backend theme. But My account page has to take front end theme .. Please help us to resolve on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage it I use the module [Administration theme](http://drupal.org/project/admin_theme) that allows me to manage different pages and force Drupal to use back-office theme or front

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the module mentioned above ?